# Global variables are not global - only within function

Tags: javascript, variables, gps

I watch the visitors position and stores the current coordinates in two variables, `latitude` and `longitude`. When the visitor clicks on the map, the new marker's coordinates will be stored in another two variables, `click_latitude` and `click_longitude`.

When this is done, I want to show the marker's coordinates in the span `.test` as text. The problem is that `coordinates_click` (which contains `click_latitude` and `click_longitude`) are always empty! The coordinates for the marker are only stored in the variables within `map.on('click', function(e1) { ... }` and can not be accessed outside the function.

Why and how can I fix this?

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {

    // VARIABLES
    var gps_timeout = 10 * 1000 * 1000;


    // MAP
    map = L.map('map', {
        maxZoom: 17,
        minZoom: 7
    }).setView([59.380767, 13.503022], 13);

    // MAP (copyright)
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
    }).addTo(map);


    // GPS
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: gps_timeout,
        maximumAge: 0
    });


    // ADD MARKER
    map.on('click', function(e1) {

        // IF
        if(typeof(marker) === 'undefined') {
            marker = new L.marker(e1.latlng).addTo(map);

            var position = marker.getLatLng();
            var click_latitude = position.lat.toFixed(6);
            var click_longitude = position.lng.toFixed(6);
            map.panTo(new L.LatLng(click_latitude, click_longitude));

        // IF
        } else {
            marker.setLatLng(e1.latlng);

            var position = marker.getLatLng();
            var click_latitude = position.lat.toFixed(6);
            var click_longitude = position.lng.toFixed(6);
            map.panTo(new L.LatLng(click_latitude, click_longitude));
        }

    });


// IF
} else {
    // error handler
}



function success(position) {

    // VARIABLES
    latitude = position.coords.latitude.toFixed(6);
    longitude = position.coords.longitude.toFixed(6);
    coordinates_current = latitude + ',' + longitude;
    coordinates_click = window.click_latitude + ',' + window.click_longitude;


    // IF
    if(coordinates_click !== '') {
        $('.test').text(coordinates_click);
    }

}
```

If you want to try, please go to https://erik-edgren.nu/map. <s>The code above is updated to the current code.</s> Please see the my answer below.

Comment: You can declare `click_` vars globally, outside of the function. Then just drop `var click_` from your functions. Or, access them from the function with `window.click_ = ...`.

Comment: Ok. I added `click_latitude, click_longitude` under `var gps_timeout = ...` and got this error message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: click_latitude is not defined`

Comment: In which line? What environment/browser you use? Have you tried accessing them through `window`?

Comment: After line 4 in the code in my question. After that, I tried to remove line 5 that I added (as mentioned) and changed the line 62 from `var click_latitude, click_longitude;` to `window.click_latitude;` on line 62 and `window.click_longitude;` for line 63. This gave me the same error message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: click_latitude is not defined`

Comment: Does the error message say in which line is the error?

Comment: Yes: `success @ map:265`. That line is this one: `coordinates_click = click_latitude + ',' + click_longitude;`. I tested to remove line 62 and 63 and changed line 66 (as in my code in my question, which I have updated to the current code) to this: `coordinates_click = window.click_latitude + ',' + window.click_longitude;`. The error message was completely gone after that, but `coordinates_click` says `undefined,undefined`, even after I clicked on the map :/

Comment: Please see the link for further tests in my updated question.

Comment: Ok, so you should always assign to `window.click_ = ...` in your `map` functions, and then read from `window.click_` in your `success` function. You should also remove `var click_` declarations from all functions.

Comment: Thank you. I've change all `... click_` to `window.click_` but it shows the same: `undefined,undefined`. **EDIT** Hm. the coordinates will be updated upon tab switch in Google Chrome.

Comment: Now your `latitude` is undefined in line `directions_(latitude + ..`. You should use a debugger (in Chrome for example, see [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)).

Comment: Thank you for noticing that. I will take a look at it when I have got some sleep :) Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. I posted an answer to summarize the solution of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are declaring `click_latitude` and `click_longitude` *local to your event functions* (map `click` handler and `success` function). `var` declarations always have a function scope.

If you wish to share a variable between several functions, you can use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) (see also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/404556)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var click_latitude, click_longitude;
    ...
    map.on('click', function(e1) {
        click_latitude = ...
        click_longitude = ...
    }
    ...
    function success(position) {
        var coordinates_click = click_latitude + ',' + click_longitude;
        $('.test').text(coordinates_click);
    }
}
```

or a global variable (property of the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window) [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    map.on('click', function(e1) {
        window.click_latitude = ...
        window.click_longitude = ...
    }
    ...
    function success(position) {
        var coordinates_click = window.click_latitude + ',' + window.click_longitude;
        $('.test').text(coordinates_click);
    }
}
```